# simple jquery redirection based on country not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery

can you make me understand why this code seems to not work properly?

```
    <html><head><title></title>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script>
jQuery.ajax( {
  url: '//freegeoip.net/json/',
  type: 'POST',
  dataType: 'jsonp',
  success: function(location) {
    // If the visitor is browsing from Romania or GB
    if (location.country_code === 'RO' || 'GB') {
      // Redirect him to the Canadian store.
      window.top.location.href = 'http://shop-in-canada.myshopify.com';
    }
else
{ return false; }
  }
} );
</script>
</head><body></body></html>
```

By properly i mean that this redirects me on shop-in-canada.myshopify.com even i have GB or RO or US or CA or any other country. Where do you think the problem is coming from?

Comment: Could you try with this below your ```dataType``` , ```data: JSON.stringify```

Comment: This return "XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://freegeoip.net/json/. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin ' site .com' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 405." in console. But thanks for trying to help. @saravanan answer helped me with all i needed!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should replace

```
if (location.country_code === 'RO' || 'GB') {
   // Redirect him to the Canadian store.
   window.top.location.href = 'http://shop-in-canada.myshopify.com';
}
```

to

```
if (location.country_code === 'RO' || location.country_code === 'GB') {
   // Redirect him to the Canadian store.
   window.top.location.href = 'http://shop-in-canada.myshopify.com';
}
```

For multiple check, do

```
var language = ["RO", "GB"];
if (language.indexOf(location.country_code) !== -1) {
   // Redirect him to the Canadian store.
   window.top.location.href = 'http://shop-in-canada.myshopify.com';
}
```

Comment: This worked. Thanks, but isn't here any way to not repeat location.country_code every time?

Comment: Great, thats awesome. Thanks very much.

Comment: Glad I could help. Kindly accept the answer so that I might guide others. :)

Comment: I m sorry mate but i can't accept  the answer because i do not have enough reputation.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (location.country_code === 'RO' || 'GB')
```

Won't work. Logging that line, you don't get `true` or `false` back, but instead you get `"GB"`.

Simply replacing the above with

`if (location.country_code === 'RO' || location.country_code === 'GB')`

will do the trick.

Comment: Just an FYI: Using that website might not be your best bet, as I have an ad-blocker, and it wasn't working for me without disabling that first.

Comment: What is your advice for me to use for not being blocked by adblock? @fibrechips

Comment: It's possible to send freegeoip an IP address: https://freegeoip.net/json/xxx.xx.xx.xxx -- Just send the client's IP address from your server and redirect based on the response there instead of doing it client-side.

Comment: And how could i do it?  could you explain what i should use and how?  @americanumlaut

Comment: @Adrian, I agree with AmericanUmlaut on that. You could even setup an AWS Lambda instance if you don't expect tons of people to use it (Under 1M requests a month is free, and it's cheap for more.), or you could look into setting up something like a Node.js server yourself.

I'm not gonna tell you any more than that, because then where's the fun for you? :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can try this way where you have to do for each country code.

```
jQuery.ajax( {
                url: '//freegeoip.net/json/',
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'jsonp',
                success: function(location) {
                    if (location.country_code === 'US') {
                        // do nothing
                    }
                    else if (location.country_code === 'AU') {
                        window.location.href = 'http://yoururlhere.com';
                    }
                    else if (location.country_code === 'SE') {
                         window.location.href = 'http://yoururlhere.com';
                    }
                    else if (location.country_code === 'NL') {
                        window.location.href = 'http://yoururlhere.com';
                    }
                    else if (location.country_code === 'GB') {
                       // window.location.href = 'http://yoururlhere.com';
                    }
                }
            });
```

Comment: Thanks, but is more practical for me to use if(var = 'country1' || var = 'country2' || var = 'country3' || var = 'country4' || var = 'countr5y' || var = 'country6' || var = 'country7') because i try to redirect all those countries to a single url, the the rest to other.